# superimpose UIActivityInidicator on UISwitch

Tags: ios

i have a uiswitch in each tableViewCell that initiates a network action. I want to superimpose a uiActivityInidicator over the switch until the server answers. I have seen this done with a uibarbutton.

I have added code to this previously working method that has a subclassed UISwitch, but no spinner is displayed.

any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)changeState:(id)sender {
    Plug *plug = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:       ((NamedUISwitch*)sender).indexPath];
    if(((NamedUISwitch*)sender).on){
        plug.state = @"1";
    } else {
        plug.state = @"0";
    }


    NamedUISwitch *theSwitch=(NamedUISwitch*)sender;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView    alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [theSwitch addSubview:spinner];
    // send message to server
 }
```

Comment: my apologies. This actually does work. the spinner just doesn't have much contrast, and you can barely see it against the white background of the switch.

Comment: As of iOS 5.x, why not set it's color property?

Comment: great idea! I didn't realize that property could be set!

Comment: Shall I post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 5.x, UIActivityIndicator conforms to UIAppearance, and so it now has a [color property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIActivityIndicatorView/color) which changes the color of the spinner.